# SQL How to add OR to sum(CASE from 2 different columns to 1

Tags: sql

I have a SQL code which sums datas to 2 different columns:

```
 sum(CASE WHEN u.data LIKE 'first%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS first_test,
 sum(CASE WHEN u.data LIKE 'second%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS second_test
```

which adds 2 columns like this:

```
first_test   second_test
-------------------------
13042           676
11950           798
105136          8745
17516           776
```

I want to achieve sum of those 2 to 1 column which contains both of datas `'first%'` and  `'second%'`. I tried something like this:

```
 sum(CASE WHEN u.data LIKE 'first%' OR 'second%' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS total
```

to have 1 column with sum of `first_test` and `second_test` which is:

```
total
-------
13718
12748
113881
18292
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `OR` the first and second `LIKE` conditions:

```
sum(CASE WHEN u.data LIKE 'first%' OR u.data LIKE 'second%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total
```

(Note that I've changed from `ELSE NULL` to `ELSE 0`, to avoid the *Null values eliminated in set function* warning.)

Comment: Oh, I just missed another u.data obviously, so simple.. Thank you for the quick answer